# What is the point of the assign() function in Mage_Rating_Block_Entity_Detailed?

Tags: magento-1, ratings, code-analysis

I'm studying Magento and trying to wrap my head around the way this particular function is set up. In the `Mage_Rating_Block_Entity_Detailed` block, this line creates the $collection variable that can be used in the phtml template:

```
$this->assign('collection', $ratingCollection);
```

The assign function, found in the `Mage_Core_Block_Template` block, goes like this:

```
public function assign($key, $value=null)
    {
        if (is_array($key)) {
            foreach ($key as $k=>$v) {
                $this->assign($k, $v);
            }
        }
        else {
            $this->_viewVars[$key] = $value;
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

This uses the _viewVars function, which I haven't found much on--but from what I can tell, it just takes the `$key` variable ('collection' in this case) and makes it into a proper variable ($collection) with the assigned value.

So why bother with all of this? Why not just replace the assign function with something like:

```
$collection = $ratingCollection;
```

Or, for that matter, why bother renaming `$ratingCollection` at all? There obviously must be some need for the fancy footwork here, but I don't see it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So as you said the `assign` method deals with the `$_viewVars` variable of `Mage_Core_Block_Template`.

You missed the interested part though.

In the `fetchView` method you can find the following line:

```
extract ($this->_viewVars, EXTR_SKIP);
```

That means that using the following code:

```
$this->assign('collection', $ratingCollection);
```

Your `.phtml` template view file will have access to a local variable called `$collection`.

As you can see in the `app/design/base/default/template/rating/detailed.phtml` file, the `$collection` is not declared in the template directly as it comes from this `assign` method:

```
<?php if(!empty($collection) && $collection->getSize()): ?>
    <table class="ratings-table">
        <col width="1" />
        <col />
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($collection as $_rating): ?>
                <?php if($_rating->getSummary()): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th><?php echo $this->__($this->escapeHtml($_rating->getRatingCode())) ?></th>
                        <td>
                            <div class="rating-box">
                                <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo ceil($_rating->getSummary()) ?>%;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endif; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

You can find more information here if you'd like to: http://magento-quickies.alanstorm.com/post/19574557297/using-assign-with-magento-blocks

Comment: That makes sense, but why is that preferable over just declaring the $collection variable in the block php file? Obviously, you would have to declare it outside of a function, so would that make its scope too large and potentially conflict with other parts of the app?

Comment: @sadq3377 I think it's a matter of less code to write. I'm not sure but as this block is only used once in the `getReviewsSummaryHtml` method, declaring a `$collection` variable in the block file will imply to create a function to retrieve that collection in the template file as well as adding an extra line in the template to call that method. To me that's what it looks like.